# VBA Chart Title

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I run this code more than once, only the first chart get label and every other chart after that shows up as chart title.

```
Sub LineChart()
    
Range("A2:M6").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2 201, xlLine
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Monthly Sales"

EndSub


Sub ColumnChart()

Range("A2:M6").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2 201, xlColumnClustered
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Monthly Sales"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe loop through the charts?

Comment: Not familiar with chart APIs, but if `AddChart2` is a function, I bet it returns a reference to the `ChartObject` you mean to be interacting with. Try `With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Add(201, xlLine)`, and then `.chart.ChartTitle.Text="Monthly Sales"` and `End With`.

Comment: Running it a second time is still going to use `A2:M6` for a source though.

Answer (score 0):

loop through charts and give chart numbers as variable. Most probably you need to change Source data every time.